How to force solving a Root[] expression?
As a subexpression of a result I get a third root of a parametrized cubic polynomial like this:
Root[b^3-b^3*z + 3*b^2*#1 + 3*#1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]
Solve can do this using the cubic formula:
Solve[b^3-b^3*z+3*b^2*x +3*x^2+x^3 == 0, x][[3]]
Gives the expected output.
How can I force the Root expression to evaluate when it's inside a larger formula?

How about using ToRadicals?

Thanks, using expr /. rt_Root :> ToRadicals[rt] does the job.
